# Firefox use lot of cpu

Tags: firefox, performance

I have a notebook nb510 Toshiba with Ubuntu 12.04 and firefox 22.0 with extensions like addock-plus, x-notifier, download helper, xmarks. Sometimes it's take more cpu than 100%
This information of firefox:

```
@nb510:~$ top

top - 02:23:57 up 18 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.42, 0.39, 0.36
Tasks: 153 total,   1 running, 152 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.9%us,  0.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2047344k total,   741132k used,  1306212k free,    54984k buffers
Swap:  2068352k total,        0k used,  2068352k free,   370208k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND   
 2320 john      20   0  576m 117m  36m S   117  5.9   1:31.67 firefox          
 1015 root      20   0  120m  39m 7588 S    9  2.0   2:02.09 Xorg     
 2088 john      20   0 92592  15m  11m S    7  0.8   0:11.30 gnome-terminal     
 2183 john      20   0  2852 1176  888 R    1  0.1   0:08.58 top                
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:06.83 kworker/1:0        
    1 root      20   0  3636 2052 1316 S    0  0.1   0:01.80 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0        
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0        
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.24 watchdog/0         
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1        
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.13 ksoftirqd/1        
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.05 watchdog/1         
   13 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2        
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/2        
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2         
   17 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3        
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.88 kworker/3:0
```

and this from firefox

```
  Paramètres de base de l'application

        Nom
        Firefox

        Version
        22.0

        Agent utilisateur
        Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0

        Configuration de compilation

          about:buildconfig

  Extensions

        Nom

        Version

        Activée

        ID

        British English Dictionary
        1.19.1
        true
        en-GB@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org

        DownloadHelper
        4.9.17
        true
        {b9db16a4-6edc-47ec-a1f4-b86292ed211d}

        Element Hiding Helper pour Adblock Plus
        1.2.3
        true
        elemhidehelper@adblockplus.org

        Ubuntu Firefox Modifications
        2.6
        true
        ubufox@ubuntu.com

        Xmarks
        4.2.1
        true
        foxmarks@kei.com

        X-notifier
        3.3.3
        true
        {37fa1426-b82d-11db-8314-0800200c9a66}

  Préférences modifiées importantes

      Nom

      Valeur

        accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar
        0

        browser.cache.disk.capacity
        1048576

        browser.cache.disk.smart_size_cached_value
        1048576

        browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run
        false

        browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion
        4

        browser.startup.homepage
        http://www.google.fr/ig

        browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID
        20130627161504

        browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone
        22.0

        dom.mozApps.used
        true

        extensions.lastAppVersion
        22.0

        network.cookie.prefsMigrated
        true

        places.database.lastMaintenance
        1375143077

        places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages
        52413

        plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types
        application/pdf

        plugin.importedState
        true

        privacy.sanitize.migrateFx3Prefs
        true

        security.warn_viewing_mixed
        false

        storage.vacuum.last.index
        0

        storage.vacuum.last.places.sqlite
        1375140331

  Accélération graphique

        Description de la carte
        VMware, Inc. -- Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)

        Fenêtres avec accélération graphique
        0/1 Basic Bloqué pour la version de votre pilote graphique.

        ID du périphérique
        Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)

        ID du vendeur
        VMware, Inc.

        Rendu WebGL
        Bloqué pour la version de votre pilote graphique.

        Version du pilote
        2.1 Mesa 8.0.4

        AzureCanvasBackend
        cairo

        AzureContentBackend
        none

        AzureFallbackCanvasBackend
        none

  JavaScript

        Ramasse-miettes incrémentiel
        true

  Accessibilité

        Activée
        false

        Empêcher l'accessibilité
        0

  Versions des bibliothèques

        Version minimale attendue

        Version utilisée

        NSPR
        4.9.6
        4.9.6

        NSS
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC

        NSSSMIME
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC

        NSSSSL
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC
        3.14.3.0 Basic ECC

        NSSUTIL
        3.14.3.0
        3.14.3.0
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can configure XMarks to run only when closing Firefox, or when you manually ask it to sync. Occasionally ABP will contact the internet to download new blocking rules. In my experience, this is quite normal behaviour for Firefox when some extensions are installed. We are still waiting for Firefox profiler tools to track down which plugins are hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to me that you aren't using the *Hardware Acceleration* (which could lead to high CPU consumption, or your hardware don't support it). If you have your Video drivers updated and correctly configured, you could force Firefox to use Hardware acceleration:

1. Open `about:config`, accept that you know what you are doing (technically it's me)
2. Search for `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`. If it's not created, right click an empty area, hit New > Boolean, and name it as `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`.
3. Right click `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and hit **Toggle**.
4. Restart firefox and check your CPU consumption, should be manageable now.

### How to know if you have HW-Accel

1. Open up a terminal.
2. Run `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`
3. Once it finish run `glxinfo | grep render`
4. It should have a line that reads:

   direct rendering: **Yes**

   OpenGL renderer string: **Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515** *(this line could be whatever)*

If it's says **No** or the second line says **Software rasterizer** it means you <strike>are doomed</strike> needs to configure your video card (if it supports HWA) or buying a new shinny card.

Comment: Does not work. I enabled the setting in firefox, and have rendering enabled. Firefox still using > 100% CPU to do anything.

Comment: @Dave check about:performance and see which tabs are doing that. It could be a misbehaving page with some JS loop.

Answer (score 5):

Quite possible is that the root of the slowdown is one or several of installed FF extensions. Try disabling them one by one to see if they cause the problem. Initially, you may disable all of them to see if FF consumes significantly less resources in your case (there is an option in `Help` menu `Restart with Add-ons Disabled...`)

See a detailed instruction here: 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems

UPD:
There is a list of known problematic FF extensions, to ease problem detection:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problematic_extensions

Answer (score 2):

I found the posting of @Hadi in a similar thread. [Link deleted because offline]

Try this solution

1. Open Firefox.
2. Type 'about:Config' into the address line and hit Go or return. This takes you into the Firefox expert Config menu.
3. See if there is an entry called browser.cache.disk.capacity.
4. If Yes then modify the value to 16384, close Firefox and restart
   Firefox.
5. If No right click somewhere on the about:Config page and select Integer. Create an Integer entry called 'browser.cache.memory.capacity' and set it to 16384. Close Firefox and restart Firefox.

If this solution not work then install an AdBlock extension such as Adblock Plus

Comment: Why should the value be 16384?

Comment: I have no idea. But it worked for me.

Comment: Did not work, CPU still > 100% with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Since the upgrade to Firefox 104.0.2 (32-bit) it uses a lot of CPU and heats up the processor.

Solution - Open a terminal and enter the following commands

1. sudo renice -n x -u username
2. htop and search for firefox PID
3. sudo cpulimit --pid xxxx --limit 80 --background

Is the only working interim solution for me and my old 32-bit OS.