# Ubuntu 20.04 - Browsers are taking 100% of CPU

Tags: 20.04, xfce

From last few days, any browser I open (with even a single tab) immediately starts using high CPU and the whole system lags. I have tried with various browsers and all of them behaving more or less same. The `Chromium` based ones (`Brave`, `Google Chrome` etc) are taking more than 100% of CPU while `Firefox` takes around 60-65% all the time. As a result, the system immediately becomes sluggish.

I inspected the processes using `htop` and when using `Chromium` based browsers, everytime the process which is using high CPU is having `--type=gpu-process` flag. Also, as soon as the browser process gets frenzy, the `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` process also starts utilizing 25-30% of CPU immediately.

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 on a i7-6600U/16GB RAM/512 SSD. I have using 20.04 for months, and the problem occurred from last few days only.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have noticed that the fonts are not getting displayed properly.

Take a look at the same page in Chrome vs Firefox
[image: take a look at the same page in Chrome vs Firefox]
This posts edit text in Firefox
[image: This posts edit text in Firefox]

Comment: Look for some answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/326281/firefox-use-lot-of-cpu and let us all know if you make any progress with Firefox as the browser.

Comment: @darth_epoxy seems hardware acceleration already enabled

Comment: Are there any errors logged into syslog during browser startup?

Comment: nothing suspicious apart from during starting up Brave, it is logging this:  `dbus-daemon[861]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.137' (uid=618169188 pid=23889 comm="/opt/brave.com/brave/brave " label="unconfined")`

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. The only way to resolve it is to use the Opera browser so far. Chrome is not an option and Firefox has performance problems.

I hope the Brave browser is able to patch. I really love the Brave browser experience on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar symptoms. It turned out, however, that during an upgrade of my SSD disk, I had managed to turn off swap. Correcting the swap device name in `/etc/fstab` followed by `sudo /sbin/swapon -a` immediately fixed the issue. A bit strange, though, that FF does not die with an OutOfMemory error.